# Reading JSON from a file

Tags: python, json

A simple looking, easy statement is throwing some errors in my face.

I have a JSON file called *strings.json* like this:

```
"strings": [{"-name": "city", "#text": "City"}, {"-name": "phone", "#text": "Phone"}, ...,
            {"-name": "address", "#text": "Address"}]
```

I want to read the JSON file, just that for now. I have these statements which I found out, but it's not working:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('strings.json') as json_data:
    d = json.loads(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    pprint(d)
```

The error displayed on the console was this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../android/values/manipulate_json.py", line 5, in <module>
    d = json.loads(json_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

---

If I use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../android/values/manipulate_json.py", line 5, in <module>
    d = json.load(json_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 829 column 1 - line 829 column 2 (char 18476 - 18477)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file contains valid JSON?

Comment: See also: [Read & Write example for JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769)

Comment: Your file is an invalid json format. Change it to:

`{"strings": [{"-name": "city", "#text": "City"}, {"-name": "phone", "#text": "Phone"}, ...,
            {"-name": "address", "#text": "Address"}]}`

Comment: ...i.e. the thing that's invalid about the input is that it's missing the surrounding {} braces.

Comment: If you are reading the data from the Internet instead, the same techniques can generally be used with the response you get from your HTTP API (it will be a file-like object); however, it is heavily recommended to use the third-party Requests library instead, which includes built-in support for JSON requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python for details; note that multiple answers all mention Requests.

Comment: Do we really need the `json_data.close()` here? It would be called automatically in the end of the scope of `with` statement.

Comment: Someone accidentally showed me a much better canonical today, which I further improved by editing the question for style, cleaning up the title, and adding my own comprehensive answer. The question is here: [How can I parse and use JSON?](/questions/7771011) and it is properly **focused** on dealing with compliant data. I closed this as a duplicate because it is not suitable for use as a canonical, since it conflates two issues - the actual reading and parsing, and a defect in the data. We are still missing a good canonical to explain common problems in JSON data.

Answer (score 875, accepted):

The [`json.load()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) (without "s" in "load") can read a file directly:

```
import json

with open('strings.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    print(d)
```

You were using the [`json.loads()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), which is used for *string* arguments only.

---

The error you get with `json.loads` is a totally different problem. In that case, there is some invalid JSON content in that file. For that, I would recommend running the file through a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/).

There are also solutions for fixing JSON like for example *[How do I automatically fix an invalid JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514910/how-do-i-automatically-fix-an-invalid-json-string)*.

Answer (score 122):

Here is a copy of code which works fine for me,

```
import json

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print(json_data)
```

with the data

```
{
    "a": [1,3,"asdf",true],
    "b": {
        "Hello": "world"
    }
}
```

You may want to wrap your *json.load* line with a *try catch*, because invalid JSON will cause a stacktrace error message.

Answer (score 49):

The problem is using the **with** statement:

```
with open('strings.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    pprint(d)
```

The file is going to be implicitly closed already. There is no need to call `json_data.close()` again.

Comment: to pretty-print, I had to use: `print(json.dumps(d,sort_keys=True,indent=2))`

Comment: What about the invalid JSON input in the question?

Answer (score 45):

In Python 3, we can use the below method.

**Read from a file and convert to JSON**

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

# Considering "json_list.json" is a JSON file

with open('json_list.json') as fd:
     json_data = json.load(fd)
     pprint(json_data)
```

The **with** statement automatically closes the opened file descriptor.

---

**String to JSON**

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data = json.loads('{"name" : "myName", "age":24}')
pprint(json_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

To add on this, today you are able to use pandas to
import JSON: *[pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)*

You may want to do a careful use of the orient parameter.

Comment: This answer would be better if you add code examples as well as the url...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) library to read the JSON file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('strings.json', lines=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
def read_JSON():
    with open("FILE PATH", "r") as i:
        JSON_data = i.read()
    print(JSON_data)
```

Comment: All this does is open the JSON file and read it into a variable, not parsing it; are you sure this is what OP wants?

Comment: Yes, this will help to read JSON objects to utilize them as a request payload or for any other purpose. I am using this for my current API request implementation and it is working fine for me.

Comment: If you have to parse the file, then `.read` would be a bad way of doing it, since you'll have to reimplement what the json module already does.

Comment: I think LOAD will reimplement the JSON with python dictionary but READ helps to load the JSON directly to the data frame