# Reading scraped json file into python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to read a JSON file I've scraped from a website into Python, with the eventual aim of turning it into a csv file for later statistical analysis.

An example of the file I want to read is:

```
globals.jsonpCallback('/feed/match/1-1-8vOt3JMq-1-2-yj0a9.dat', {"s":1,"d":{"bt":1,"sc":2,"st":{"notice":"finished","status-name":"Finished","result-name":"<p id=\"event-status\" class=\"result\"><span class=\"bold\" id=\"event-status-finished\">Final result 3:1<\/span><\/p>"},"oddsdata":{"back":{"E-1-2-0-0-0":{"handicapType":0,"handicapValue":"0.00","odds":{"49":{"0":1.32,"2":7,"1":4.8},"46":{"0":1.33,"2":7.3,"1":4.5},"9":{"0":1.25,"2":12,"1":5},"16":{"0":1.29,"2":11,"1":5},"164":{"0":1.31,"2":7.59,"1":4.5},"18":{"0":1.24,"2":11.6,"1":5.25},"23":{"0":1.27,"2":11.23,"1":4.75},"26":{"0":1.3,"2":10.5,"1":5},"5":{"0":1.23,"2":12,"1":5.75},"44":{"0":1.14,"2":4,"1":2.52},"1":{"0":1.3,"2":8.5,"1":4.4},"8":{"0":1.25,"2":9,"1":5},"3":{"0":1.25,"2":11,"1":4.5},"31":{"0":1.25,"2":9,"1":4.5},"60":{"0":1.29,"2":8.5,"1":4.5},"15":{"0":1.28,"2":10,"1":5.4},"34":{"0":1.25,"2":10,"1":5},"111":{"0":1.25,"2":10,"1":4.84},"68":{"0":1.26,"2":9.75,"1":4.84},"105":{"0":1.28,"2":8,"1":4.5},"71":{"0":1.3,"2":9,"1":5},"28":{"0":1.25,"2":12,"1":5.5},"33":{"0":1.3,"2":9.25,"1":4.84},"14":{"0":1.22,"2":10.93,"1":5.05},"21":{"0":1.33,"2":7.5,"1":4.33},"30":{"0":1.22,"2":8.5,"1":5.5},"24":{"0":1.3,"2":9,"1":4.95},"32":{"0":1.25,"2":9.5,"1":4.9},"2":{"0":1.25,"2":10,"1":5},"90":{"0":1.28,"2":10.25,"1":4.8},"56":{"0":1.3,"2":9.8,"1":4.8},"41":{"0":1.3,"2":8.9,"1":4.5},"128":{"0":1.27,"2":12,"1":5.5},"75":{"0":1.2,"2":10.5,"1":5.2}},"mixedParameterId":0,"OutcomeID":{"0":"s3nfxv464x0x1o7d5","2":"s3nfxv464x0x1o7d6","1":"s3nfxv498x0x0"},"opening_odds":{"49":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"46":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"9":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"16":{"0":1.22,"2":null,"1":null},"164":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"18":{"0":1.31,"2":9.8,"1":5.65},"23":{"0":null,"2":4.75,"1":11.23},"26":{"0":1.25,"2":10,"1":5.25},"5":{"0":1.22,"2":12.5,"1":5.5},"44":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"1":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"8":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"3":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"31":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"60":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"15":{"0":1.25,"2":null,"1":4.5},"34":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"111":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"68":{"0":1.27,"2":9.15,"1":4.65},"105":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"71":{"0":1.29,"2":8,"1":4.5},"28":{"0":1.22,"2":10,"1":5},"33":{"0":1.4,"2":6.65,"1":4.25},"14":{"0":1.32,"2":7.8,"1":4.42},"21":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"30":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"24":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"32":{"0":1.3,"2":8.5,"1":4.75},"2":{"0":1.35,"2":7.75,"1":4.3},"90":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"56":{"0":null,"2":11,"1":4.59},"41":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"128":{"0":1.25,"2":null,"1":5},"75":{"0":1.25,"2":8.9,"1":4.8}},"opening_change_time":{"49":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"46":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"9":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"16":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"164":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"18":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"23":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"26":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"5":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"44":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"1":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"8":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"3":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"31":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"60":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"15":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"34":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"111":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"68":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"105":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"71":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"28":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"33":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"14":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"21":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"30":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"24":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"32":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"2":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"90":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"56":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"41":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"128":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false},"75":{"0":false,"2":false,"1":false}},"opening_volume":{"49":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"46":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"9":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"16":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"164":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"18":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"23":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"26":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"5":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"44":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"1":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"8":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"3":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"31":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"60":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"15":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"34":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"111":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"68":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"105":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"71":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"28":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"33":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"14":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"21":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"30":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"24":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"32":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"2":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"90":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"56":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"41":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"128":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null},"75":{"0":null,"2":null,"1":null}},"volume":[],"change_time":{"49":{"0":1192344925,"2":1192344925,"1":1192344925},"46":{"0":1192356640,"2":1192356640,"1":1192356640},"9":{"0":1192374117,"2":1192374117,"1":1192374117},"16":{"0":1192643462,"2":1192643462,"1":1192643462},"164":{"0":1192356640,"2":1192356640,"1":1192356640},"18":{"0":1192643462,"2":1192642538,"1":1192643462},"23":{"0":1192528549,"2":1192533516,"1":1192533516},"26":{"0":1192643462,"2":1192527200,"1":1192643462},"5":{"0":1192617648,"2":1192617648,"1":1192617648},"44":{"0":1192054308,"2":1192054308,"1":1192054308},"1":{"0":1192383076,"2":1192383076,"1":1192383076},"8":{"0":1192364254,"2":1192364254,"1":1192364254},"3":{"0":1192430433,"2":1192430433,"1":1192430433},"31":{"0":1192365159,"2":1192365159,"1":1192365159},"60":{"0":1192389374,"2":1192389374,"1":1192389374},"15":{"0":1192610985,"2":1192310256,"1":1192610985},"34":{"0":1192366959,"2":1192366959,"1":1192366959},"111":{"0":1192487538,"2":1192487538,"1":1192487538},"68":{"0":1192473161,"2":1192473161,"1":1192473161},"105":{"0":1192354376,"2":1192354376,"1":1192354376},"71":{"0":1192610985,"2":1192610985,"1":1192610985},"28":{"0":1192570418,"2":1192570418,"1":1192570418},"33":{"0":1192397461,"2":1192397461,"1":1192397461},"14":{"0":1192641649,"2":1192641649,"1":1192641649},"21":{"0":1192362474,"2":1192362474,"1":1192362474},"30":{"0":1192356171,"2":1192356171,"1":1192356171},"24":{"0":1192419956,"2":1192419956,"1":1192419956},"32":{"0":1192635347,"2":1192635347,"1":1192635347},"2":{"0":1192449725,"2":1192449725,"1":1192449725},"90":{"0":1192426261,"2":1192426261,"1":1192426261},"56":{"0":1192366052,"2":1192621850,"1":1192621850},"41":{"0":1192436180,"2":1192436180,"1":1192436180},"128":{"0":1192624523,"2":1192441597,"1":1192624523},"75":{"0":1192437084,"2":1192437084,"1":1192437084}},"st":{"49":[3,60],"46":[3,60],"9":[3,60],"16":[3,60],"164":[3,60],"18":[3,60],"23":[3,60],"26":[3,60],"5":[3,60],"44":[3,60],"1":[3,60],"8":[3,60],"3":[3,60],"31":[3,60],"60":[3,60],"15":[3,60],"34":[3,60],"111":[3,60],"68":[3,60],"105":[3,60],"71":[3,60],"28":[3,60],"33":[3,60],"14":[3,60],"21":[3,60],"30":[3,60],"24":[3,60],"32":[3,60],"2":[3,60],"90":[3,60],"56":[3,60],"41":[3,60],"128":[3,60],"75":[3,60]},"bs":[],"act":{"49":true,"46":true,"9":true,"16":true,"164":true,"18":true,"23":true,"26":true,"5":true,"44":true,"1":true,"8":true,"3":true,"31":true,"60":true,"15":true,"34":false,"111":true,"68":true,"105":true,"71":true,"28":true,"33":true,"14":true,"21":true,"30":false,"24":true,"32":true,"2":true,"90":true,"56":true,"41":true,"128":true,"75":true},"actEx":{"44":{"0":true,"2":true,"1":true}}}},"lay":[]},"history":{"back":null,"lay":null},"hcl":true,"time-base":1192644000,"nav":{"1":{"2":["1","2","3","5","8","9","14","15","16","18","21","23","24","26","28","30","31","32","33","34","41","44","46","49","56","60","68","71","75","90","105","111","128","164"]},"4":{"2":["2","5","9","23","46","49","164"]}},"hasLiveOdds":false,"brokenParser":["30","34","103","154"],"hash":"c9fff233b9f89d1da10e81a9fdae7c14"},"refresh":16});
```

My current code looks like this (previous copy and paste job was inexplicably wrong):

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data = open('/home/readejj/Documents/data/1-1-jFEwehyT-1-2-yjaf9.dat').read()
json_stuff = json_data[json_data.find('{'):json_data.rfind('}')+1]
json_stuff = json_stuff.replace("\"","'")
print "json_stuff",type(json_stuff), len(json_stuff), json_stuff[1:2000]
d = json.loads(json_stuff)
pprint(d)
```

This is adopted from: [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-a-json-file-using-python)

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_json.py", line 16, in <module>
    d = json.loads(json_stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated - my apologies if it's a very basic error, I am not an experienced programmer.

UPDATE: It's been pointed out my replace line is bad - if removed, I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_oddsportal_json.py", line 19, in <module>
    d = json.loads(json_stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 99 (char 99)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the sample and the code you used. Perhaps some *other* JSON file is not well-formed or doesn't quite work with your method of slicing?

Comment: Note that your *first* `json_stuff = ` line is entirely redundant.

Comment: What does the start of the content in json_stuff look like?

Comment: Thanks - yes I think I didn't delete once I added the extra json_stuff line.

Comment: fiskfisk the start of json_stuff is the stuff copied in above, trimmed for the {}s.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
json_stuff = json_stuff.replace("\"","'")
```

is bad. Delete it.

The JSON spec requires that strings are double-quote (`"`) delimited, not single-quote.

Comment: Yes, JSON properties MUST be quoted in double-quotes, using single-quotes is ILLEGAL!

Comment: Thanks, got that idea from somewhere, but I get errors either way. If removed I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_oddsportal_json.py", line 19, in <module>
    d = json.loads(json_stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 99 (char 99)

Comment: @user2613998, that error has to do with backslash escaping. I got that error when I pasted the json into the python script, but not when I read the data from a file.  Are you **sure** that you are reading the data from a file, and that the data you are reading is precisely what appears in this question?

Comment: Thanks @Robᵩ it actually seems to work now, leaving me very confused about what was going wrong previously. Thanks everyone for their help.