# Data in json format retrieved from a text file can not be read by key names

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a text file with json data stored in UTF-8 like this:

```
{'name': u'احسان', 'family': u'شیرزادی'}
```

I've tried to read and print file data with this code:

```
file = open("output.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
print text
```

It's OK and exactly as I can see in the file. but when I try to print some part of dictionary by indexes like this:

```
file = open("output.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
print text['name']
```

An error says that:

```
    print text['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

But when I run this code directly I can see It's working:

```
temp = {'name': u'احسان', 'family': u'شیرزادی'}
print temp['name']
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: JSON requires double-quotes. Single-quotes are not legal. And the `u` outside of the string is certainly not legal. See www.json.org

Comment: The problem is that `text` is a string (read normally via `file.read`) and not a dictionary, so you can't just do `text['name']`.

Comment: @JonathanM I don't think the problem is your point. I've updated the last part of question.

Comment: @hlt So what should I do?

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi, you're never converting the json string to an object. Use `json.load` after correcting the json. The way to notate an object in Python is different than the way to notate it in JSON.

Comment: how did you add the json to the  file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Probably either by hand or by calling `str()` on the dictionary holding the data and pasting it in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `file.read()` is a string. Python cannot know that you want JSON and magically convert it.

There's a module inside of the standard library that can transform strings containing JSON into Python objects:

```
import json

with open('output.txt', 'r') as fobj:
    data = json.load(fobj)

print data['name']
```

Also, you should make sure that your JSON data is formatted correctly. As others have mentioned before me, JSON strings need double quotes. Single quotes give a syntax error. And you can't have characters like `u` outside of quotes.

```
data = {'name': u'احسان', 'family': u'شیرزادی'}

with open('output2.txt', w) as fobj:
    json.dump(data, fobj)
```

In the file `output2.txt` you will have correctly formatted JSON. To retrieve the data back into Python, you can do the same thing as above with the correct filename.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. If the data really is stored like that, its not valid json and you will have to read it in as a string. And then you cant access it like a dictionary.

But if your data looks like this in the file (note there is no u in front of words, and double quotes are used):

{"name": "احسان", "family": "شیرزادی"}

then you can read it in as json and use it like a dictionary:

```
import json

with open("testing.txt") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    print data["name"]
```

Output will be:

احسان

Answer (score 1):

Data should be in JSON format and output of `file.read()` is string not python dictionary, your have to converts it by `json.loads`. And I recommend `json.dumps` for storage your JSON (text) file.

```
import json
data  = {'name': u'احسان', 'family': u'شیرزادی'}

file = open("output.txt", "w")
file.write(json.dumps(data))
file.close()
print data

file = open("output.txt", "r")
text = json.loads(file.read())
file.close()
print text['name']
```

---

Data after dump in JSON should be have double quotes; like this;

```
{"name": "\u0627\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0646", "family": "\u0634\u06cc\u0631\u0632\u0627\u062f\u06cc"} # coding: utf-8
```

or

```
{"name": "احسان", "family": "شیرزادی"}
```

---

more information JSON python : https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

---

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Json string needs double quotes. Please check;
http://json.org/example

Also you can take a look at this example which imports json library.
[Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-a-json-file-using-python)