# Looking up matching strings in two text files of different structure

Tags: shell

I have a tab-delimited textfile A (representing a BLAST output)

```
Name1   BBBBBBBBBBBB    99.40   166 1   0   1   166 334 499 3e-82    302
Name2   DDDDDDDDDDDD    98.80   167 2   0   1   167 346 512 4e-81    298
```

and a textfile B (representing a phylogenetic dendrogram) looking like

```
"Cluster A": {
        "member": {
            "Cluster A": "BBBBBBBBBBBB This is Animal A", 
                   }, 
        "name": "Cluster A"
             }, 
    "Cluster B: {
        "member": {
            "Cluster B": "DDDDDDDDDDDD This is Animal B"
                   }, 
        "name": "cluster B"
                 }
```

I want to take the string found in the 2nd tab of textfile A (DDDDDDDDDDDD for example) and look it up in text file B. The script should then add the info found in textfile B into a new tab of textfile A :

```
Name1   BBBBBBBBBBBB    99.40   166 1   0   1   166 334 499 3e-82    302 Cluster A This is Animal A
Name2   DDDDDDDDDDDD    98.80   167 2   0   1   167 346 512 4e-81    298 Cluster B This is Animal B
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure if that is just c&p errors, but is the second one supposed to be json and just full of syntax errors? (missing closing }, single " in the middle)
In that case you could try paring it to a dict, which makes accessing and comparing a lot easier

Comment: Its indeed a json, but i have never worked with this format before.

Comment: In that case look here for some basics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-a-json-file-using-python You'll end up with a dict which gives you easy access to the member fields. A simple cuting the desired string out of the BLAST output and searching for it in the "Cluster.*" fields should do the trick

Comment: The JSON format is not adding any value. A simple tab-delimited file would be easier to work with.

Comment: @glennjackman the point is that the second input is already in json.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code which reads the data from two files
Your example is missing the outer {} which would fail in parsing that's why the code is adding it.

It then loops the cluster members and construct your desired result

```
import json                                                                 
import re                                                                   

with open("in1") as blast:                                                  
    blast_data = blast.readlines()                                             

with open("in2") as jsonfile:                                                  
    json_data = json.loads("{%s}" % jsonfile.read())                           

for bdata in blast_data:                                                       
    id = bdata.split()[1]                                                      
    for cluster in json_data:                                                  
        for member in json_data[cluster]['member']:                            
            if id in json_data[cluster]['member'][member]:                     
                print "%s %s %s" % (bdata.strip(), member, re.sub(id, '', json_data[cluster]['member'][member]))
                break
```

Comment: File "blast.py", line 8, in <module>
json_data = json.loads("{%s}" % jsonfile.read())                           
File "/opt/qiime-1.8.0/python-2.7.3-release/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/qiime-1.8.0/python-2.7.3-release/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/qiime-1.8.0/python-2.7.3-release/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

Comment: Something wrong with our python? its embedded in another software suite

Comment: I'd rather think the format of the input file is broken (maybe in combination with the code).
can you somehow validate that it parses correctly or show me a complete sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing up the json file:

```
$ cat B
[
    { "Cluster A": { "member": { "Cluster A": "BBBBBBBBBBBB This is Animal A" }, "name": "Cluster A" } }, 
    { "Cluster B": { "member": { "Cluster B": "DDDDDDDDDDDD This is Animal B" }, "name": "cluster B" } }
]
```

Then, a perl solution:

```
perl -MJSON -MPath::Class -E '
    my $data = decode_json file("B")->slurp;
    $, = "\t";
    for my $line (file("A")->slurp(chomp => 1)) {
        my @F = split /\t/, $line;
        for my $item (@$data) {
            for my $cluster (keys %$item) {
                while (my ($key, $value) = each %{$item->{$cluster}{member}} ) {
                    if ($value =~ /$F[1]\s+(.*)/) {
                        say $line, $cluster, $1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
'
```

outputs

```
Name1   BBBBBBBBBBBB    99.40   166 1   0   1   166 334 499 3e-82   302 Cluster A   This is Animal A
Name2   DDDDDDDDDDDD    98.80   167 2   0   1   167 346 512 4e-81   298 Cluster B   This is Animal B
```

For kicks, the equivalent Ruby

```
ruby -rjson -e '
  data = JSON.load File.new("B")
  File.readlines("A").each {|line|
    line.chomp!
    f = line.split("\t")
    data.each {|obj|
      obj.each_key {|cluster|
        obj[cluster]["member"].each_pair {|key, value| 
          if m = value.match(f[1] + "\s+(.*)")
            puts [line, cluster, m[1]].join("\t")
          end
        }
      }
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: Is MJSON an extra module for perl?`

Comment: [ -M[-]'module...' ]
Should import the module if you run a command with [-e|-E] 'command' ]

Comment: Yes, JSON and Path::Class are add-on modules that can be installed from cpan.org

Answer (score 0):

Shell script piece of code,

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
awk '{print $2}' file1 > tmpfile
for i in `cat tmpfile`
do
{
aa=`grep -w $i file2`
awk -v out="$aa" -v pattern="$i" ' $2 ~ pattern { print $0"   "out}' file1}
done
```

`awk '{print $2}' file1 > tmpfile`  -- Takes the pattern from first file and stores in tmp file
`aa=grep -w $i file2`  -- Matches the similar pattern from file 2 and stores the entire line in variable aa
`awk -v out="$aa" -v pattern="$i" ' $2 ~ pattern { print $0"   "out}' file1}` -- Appends the string from file2 into its corresponding matching line of file1