# How to iterate through JSON list in Python?

Tags: json, python-2.7, list

This is my json data:

```js
{
  "AccountRegion": "testaccount",
  "AssumeRole": "arn",
  "Policies": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ],
  "Region": "usa"
},
{
  "AccountRegion": "testaccount-2",
  "AssumeRole": "arn",
  "Policies": "anotherpolicy",
  "Region": "usa"
}
```

I am not able figure out how to loop through the JSON. I would like to loop through the data and get policies for each member in the dataset. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: looks duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file

Comment: I have put the json data in a variable and I have looped through the json like this with no success                                                                          
 `for data in table_data['Items']:
    region = data['Region']
    assumerole = data['AssumeRole']
    policies = data['Policies']
    for policy in table_scan['Items']['policies']:                                               
       print policy`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
arr = [{
      "AccountRegion": "testaccount",
      "AssumeRole": "arn",
      "Policies": [
        "hello",
        "world"
      ],
      "Region": "usa"
    },
    {
      "AccountRegion": "testaccount-2",
      "AssumeRole": "arn",
      "Policies": "anotherpolicy",
      "Region": "usa"
    }]

for x in range(0,len(arr)):
  print arr[x]['AccountRegion']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import json
parsedJson = json.loads(data)
for i in parsedJson:
    print parsedJson["Policies"]
```