# Urls for Json Files in Python

Tags: python, json

So I was reading this: [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file). So the person in this question was having trouble loading the JSON file that they presumably made. But **I** wanted to know if it was possible to load a JSON URL such as this: http://data.consumerfinance.gov/api/views.json. If it is possible, how would you do it? Would it be as simple as `json.load(http://data.consumerfinance.gov/api/views.json)`? If it isn't possible what would you recommend me to read this same JSON file?

PS. Someone tell how to earn reputation so I make a comment instead of having to ask a separate question.

Comment: `json.loads(requests.get(url).content)` (importing `requests` first)

Comment: Or directly with requests: `requests.get(url).json()`. See the example [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
requests.get('http://data.consumerfinance.gov/api/views.json').json()
```

You'll need to have the `requests` library installed.