# Python - Take JSON file as input to be sent to API

Tags: python, json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to write a script to take in a JSON file and return the contents of the JSON to an API. I do not use `json.dumps()` because (at least in the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)) the JSON isn't converted into a string before it gets shipped out.

```
import sys, json
from woocommerce import API

products_json = sys.argv[1]

wcapi = API(
    url=SITE_URL,
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    wp_api=True,
    version="wc/v2"
)

with open(products_json, 'r') as f:
    products_data = json.load(f)

print(wcapi.post("products/batch", products_data).json())
```

This is the contents of my JSON:

```
{
    "create": [
        {
            "name": "Woo Single #1",
            "type": "simple",
            "status": "draft",
            "regular_price": "21.99",
            "virtual": true,
            "downloadable": true,
            "downloads": [
                {
                    "name": "Woo Single",
                    "file": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/cd_4_angle.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 11
                },
                {
                    "id": 13
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "New Premium Quality",
            "type": "simple",
            "status": "draft",
            "regular_price": "21.99",
            "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
            "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 9
                },
                {
                    "id": 14
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

The error message that I get is as follows:

```
C:\Users\absol\Desktop>python apmarble-wcapi.py "test.json"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apmarble-wcapi.py", line 15, in <module>
    products_data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\absol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\absol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\absol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\absol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 40 column 9 (char 1422)
```

How can I import the JSON correctly so that it ships out as I am trying to do?

Comment: Looks like this has your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of the file are valid JSON?

Comment: @JohnRoesler Doesn't seem that way to me. Because the problem is not that I used `json.loads()`.

Comment: @wpercy Good point. I'm going to attach the contents of my JSON.

Comment: Your code works for me. Please verify that the JSON data is valid.

Comment: @Norrius I've attached it.

Comment: I see a trailing comma near the end, that's not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format error, you added an extra "," in line 39. Javascript objects are more flexible but when parsing using libraries like Python JSON you must comply with RFC 4627. Next time check this website: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

```
{
"create": [
    {
        "name": "Woo Single #1",
        "type": "simple",
        "status": "draft",
        "regular_price": "21.99",
        "virtual": true,
        "downloadable": true,
        "downloads": [
            {
                "name": "Woo Single",
                "file": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/cd_4_angle.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 11
            },
            {
                "id": 13
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "New Premium Quality",
        "type": "simple",
        "status": "draft",
        "regular_price": "21.99",
        "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 14
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trailing comma after the square bracket in line 39, please remove that and it should work fine

To avoid this error in future you can just open your json in an IDE that supports json format checking .. i use eclipse or atom IDE and just opening a json file shows if there are any syntax/formatting errors in the json data.

Json with trailing comma removed:

```
{
"create": [
    {
        "name": "Woo Single #1",
        "type": "simple",
        "status": "draft",
        "regular_price": "21.99",
        "virtual": true,
        "downloadable": true,
        "downloads": [
            {
                "name": "Woo Single",
                "file": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/cd_4_angle.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 11
            },
            {
                "id": 13
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "New Premium Quality",
        "type": "simple",
        "status": "draft",
        "regular_price": "21.99",
        "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 14
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}