# Converting JSON file to SQLITE or CSV

Tags: python, json, sqlite, csv

I'm attempting to convert a JSON file to an SQLite or CSV file so that I can manipulate the data with python. Here is where the data is housed: [JSON File](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwgg/Airports/master/airports.json).

I found a few converters online, but those couldn't handle the quite large JSON file I was working with. I tried using a python module called [sqlbiter](https://github.com/thombashi/sqlitebiter) but again, like the others, was never really able to output or convert the file.

I'm not. sure where to go now, if anyone has any recommendations or insights on how to get this data into a database, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm not looking for anyone to do it for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Are there other methods I haven't tried that I could learn?

Comment: Why not write a script to do it yourself?

Comment: I don't know how to write a script that can convert this myself. If you have any literature or can link me to a walkthrough, I could attempt it.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `data = json.loads(jsonfile)`.

Comment: You dont need to convert json files to anything to parse them in Python. All you have to do is [load the file contents into a dictionary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)  and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `pandas` module for this data processing task as follows:

1. First, you need to read the `JSON` file using `with`, `open` and `json.load`.
2. Second, you need to change the format of your file a bit by changing the large dictionary that has a main key for every airport into a list of dictionaries instead.
3. Third, you can now utilize some pandas magic to convert your list of dictionaries into a `DataFrame` using `pd.DataFrame(data=list_of_dicts)`.
4. Finally, you can utilize `pandas`'s `to_csv` function to write your DataFrame as a `CSV` file into disk.

It would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('./airports.json.txt','r') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
l = list(j.values())
df = pd.DataFrame(data=l)
df.to_csv('./airports.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is fantastic. I was working with this: `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = 'file.sqlite3'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()

with open('airports.json') as data_file:
    d = json.load(data_file)

df = json_normalize(d)
df.to_sql('airports', conn, if_exists="replace")

print(df)` but couldnt get the data to present as rows as opposed to columns. Thanks again, this is fantastic.

Comment: No problem, I think you should've added this code to your original question. I am not sure if json_normalize would work in your case since you won't be able to access the inner dictionaries using 1 key because the top level of the JSON file contains multiple keys which are the 'icao' of the airports.

Comment: Noted, I'll make sure to add more code to my question next time. And good to know regarding inner dicts. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your json file and parse it to have all the fields available, or load the contents to a dictionary,   then you could using pyodbc to write to the database these fields, or write them to the csv if you use import csv first. 
But this is just a general idea.  You need to study python and how to do every step.

For instance for writting to the database you could do something like:
        for i in range(0,max_len):
              sql_order =  "UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYTABLE.MYFIELD ...."
              cursor1.execute(sql_order)
               cursor1.commit()