# TypeError while loading JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON file:

```
{
 "pass": "test", 
 "users": "joel"
}
```

And this is my Python code:

```
with open("auth.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

This is error I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "W:/ComputerScienceDiceGame/dice.py", line 21, in 
>      data = json.load(f.read())
>    File "C:\Python33\lib\json__init__.py", line 268, in load
>      return loads(fp.read(),
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

I know this is probably easy but I can't find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Comment: remove the `s` in `loads`

Comment: lol ignore the s it was accidental

Comment: Clearly your traceback is not created from the code your showing here. Your question is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one:

```
data = json.load(f)
```

```
data = json.loads(f.read())
```

The point here is, `.load` loads JSON from a reader (file descriptor), while `.loads` loads JSON from a string that's already read into memory/buffer.

Comment: data = json.loads(f.read())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 316, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 354, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 34 - line 1 column 67 (char 33 - 66)

Comment: @JoelTeer Then your file may be corrupt or contains invalid JSON.

Comment: My json should be fine because the program enters it itself

Comment: @JoelTeer The error message says there are "extra data", maybe check again?

Comment: `auth = {
    "users": usernamelow,
    "pass": password
    } #Converting the variables/inputs to JSON


dump = json.dumps(auth) #Gathers data
print (dump) #Debug print
with open('auth.json', 'a') as outfile: #Opens the file and adds data to it
    json.dump(auth, outfile)`

Comment: I just commented out the bit that writes the json to the file and had no problems. I'm rather confused

Comment: @JoenTeer Hash `#` is an invalid character in JSON, you need `//` for comments because JSON is just JavaScript. Also, the code you post doesn't generate this error message. See [mcve].