# How to create list of nested dictionaries from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input text file containing a list of key/value pairs that I would like to read into python as a list of dictionaries but can not seem to get it to work as expected.  Note that the file is *not* in valid json format so I can not use the `json` built-in and this question is *not* a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file).  I suspect that I am missing something obvious here so any guidance is much appreciated.

```
# /tmp/tmp.txt
[{'k1': {'k2': {'k3': ['a', 'b', 'c']}}}, {'k4': {'k5': {'k6': ['v', 'x', 'y', 'z']}}}]
```

Since this file contains a list with 2 elements, I would expect the `len` to be 2 and the `type` to be `list` but that is not what I'm seeing.

```
with open('/tmp/tmp.txt', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = data_file.read()

print(len(data)) # <-- the goal is for this to show 2
print(type(data)) # <-- the goal is for this to return `list`
```

#### Output:

```
88
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: data_file.read() does just return a string. I doesn't automatically convert your file to a list. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` is a string. You can convert it to a list with `literal_eval`:

```
import ast
data_list = ast.literal_eval(data)
len(data_list)
#2
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was not previously aware of the `ast` library and will check it out further.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I didn't saw earlier that DYZ answered before me but I would like to explain my answer a bit more.

There is a module called 'ast' that have the function 'literal_eval', as the name suggest, it evaluates the information of the txt as python code and also validates the input.

```
import os, ast

with open('/tmp/tmp.txt', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = ast.literal_eval(data_file.read())

print(len(data))
print(type(data))
```

Output:

```
2
<class 'list'>
```