# How to read in this JSON file formatted as a dictonary?

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

So I am working on learning Python and have a project I am working on involving keeping track of vending machines. I was given JSON files to get the information I need, but I don't know how to read it in. My teacher said it is formatted to be read in easily with every vending machine slot as a dictionary but I am very unfamiliar with dictionaries and don't understand how to do it. If someone could quickly give me an example of how to read this in I would really appreciate it because I really don't even understand where to start.

Here is a section of the JSON file:

```
{

    "contents": [
        {
            "row": "A",
            "slots": [
                {
                    "current_stock": 2,
                    "item_name": "Coke",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 3,
                    "slot_number": 1
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 0,
                    "item_name": "Coke",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 6,
                    "slot_number": 2
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 1,
                    "item_name": "Coke",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 2,
                    "slot_number": 3
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 3,
                    "item_name": "Coke",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 3,
                    "slot_number": 4
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 2,
                    "item_name": "Coke",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 2,
                    "slot_number": 5
                },

                {
                    "current_stock": 0,
                    "item_name": "Coke",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 5,
                    "slot_number": 6
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 6,
                    "item_name": "Coke Zero",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 8,
                    "slot_number": 7
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 2,
                    "item_name": "Coke Zero",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 4,
                    "slot_number": 8
                },
                {
                    "current_stock": 4,
                    "item_name": "Coke Zero",
                    "item_price": 1.75,
                    "last_stock": 7,
                    "slot_number": 9
                }
            ]

 },
```

Comment: There's a built-in module to parse JSON: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html

Comment: Note that JSON objects and Python `dict` literals look very similar. It can be convenient, but it can also be a source of confusion.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199213/1723886 explains how to load json files. What it does is give a dictionary for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You want the json library.

To go from json to dictionary

```
x = json.loads(YourDictionary)
```

to go from dictionary to json

```
y = json.dumps(YourDictionary)
```

here's a link reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp