# How to use json file that placed in the python project?

Tags: python, json

I have project in Pycharm, and I want to use json file that placed in this project.

How can I call it?

I use this one:

```
import json

file = open('~/PycharmProjects/Test/JSON_new.json')
x = json.load(file)
```

And received the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/PycharmProjects/Test/JSON_new.json'
```

But path is correct

EDIT: I understood what is the problem. Instead of json file txt was created (but I selected json). It creates txt files, maybe, someone knows hot to solve it? I can create only .py files directly. Other files no.

Is it correct if I create scratch json file and placed it in Scratches?

Comment: By its path ? What do you want to do with ? This is  not a question of doing it "in pycharm" but rather : how to open a file on my filesystem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Comment: No, edited the description.

Comment: Not sure `~` is handled

Comment: I tried also with absolute path, with same result. The problem that it creates txt files instead of json. I don't understand why.

Comment: This can't. You can't eask to read a JSON and it creates a txt file^^ you may run the wrong or something else

Comment: I perform: double-click on project title --> new File --> file name --> select JSON in file type list. And instead of json usual txt was created. No '.json' extension near file name.

Answer (score 2):

You may like to use following path(In linux):

```
file = open('/home/<user>/PycharmProjects/Test/JSON_new.json')
```

Replace user with your username. You need to know the correct path to the file, for which you can user PWD command in terminal.

Comment: It is the same, I tried. The path is correct I took it from bash.

Comment: "~/" sign shall be replaced with "/home/<user>/" Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yes, with the same result.

Comment: Can you please try this code and see if you are getting output in the terminal:

file = open('/home/<user>/PycharmProjects/Test/JSON_new.json')
print(file.read())

If no, then you are passing wrong path in open method

Comment: Edited description.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json` module for this. You can open the file in a seperate object and pass it to `json.load` if you have a JSON string use `json.loads`.

```
import json

file = open('/path/to/json/file.json')

file_opened = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Edited the question, tried this solution, not succeed.

Comment: Is your python file in the same directory as the JSON file you're trying to open? if so, just use `file = open('filename.json')`

Comment: whats the output of `cat ~/PycharmProjects/Test/JSON_new.json`

Comment: I use MacOS. Edited description.

Comment: I found that you have figured the solution out, if my answered help can you mark it as correct ?