# Read local JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I want to read a JSON file with Python :

**Here is part of my JSON file :**

```
{ "Jointure":[ { "IDJointure":1, "societe":"S.R.T.K", "date":"2019/01/01", "heure":"05:47:00"}, { "IDJointure":2, "societe":"S.R.T.K", "date":"2019/01/01", "heure":"05:50:00"}]}
```

**This is the code :**

```
import json

data  = json.loads('Data2019.json')
for i in data['Jointure']:
   print(i)
```

**But, here is the error that was displayed**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\readJSON.py", line 4, in <module>
    data  = json.loads('Data2019.json')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>
```

Comment: open the file, read it in as a string, perform json.loads() on that string? As per the answers and some reading into the documentation, json.load() will allow for a file-like object and appears to be a better solution

Comment: here is a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Try pandas

```html
import pandas as pd
patients_df = pd.read_json('E:/datasets/patients.json')
patients_df.head()
```

Comment: No need to import a library for a simple bug fix.

Answer (score 27):

`json.loads()` expects the json data to already be a string -- so it's trying to interpret the *filename* `Data2019.json` as actual json data.

Open the file, and then pass the file object to `json.load()`:

```
with open('Data2019.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```

Answer (score 3):

don't read the file directly. Open the file it's only the contents of the file that works with the json module. Try this:

```
import json

with open('path_to_file/person.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```