# Trying to get data from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like the following (not the whole file)

```
"route-information" : [
{
    "attributes" : {"xmlns" : "http://xml.juniper.net"}, 
    "route-table" : [
    {
        "comment" : "keepalive", 
        "table-name" : [
        {
            "data" : "inet"
        }
        ], 
        "destination-count" : [
        {
            "data" : "24324"
        }
        ], 
        "total-route-count" : [
        {
            "data" : "47432"
        }
        ], 
        "active-route-count" : [
        {
            "data" : "43252"
        }
        ], 
        "holddown-route-count" : [
        {
            "data" : "0"
        }
        ], 
        "hidden-route-count" : [
        {
            "data" : "1"
        }
        ],
```

I am trying to access the 'comment' part by using python.
So far I have this:

```
import json

# read file
with open('route-table.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data["route-information"]["route-table"]["comment"])
```

Whenever I run this part I get the following error and I can't seem to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "json_test.py", line 7, in <module>
print(data["route-information"]["route-table"]["comment"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data["route-information"]` is a `list`, so you can do `data["route-information"][0]` to access the `dict` inside, same with `data["route-information"][0]["route-table"]`:

```
print(data["route-information"][0]["route-table"][0]["comment"])
```

If you intend to use `data` later and are okay with changing it's structure, you can replace the `list`s with their first elements (assuming they only have one element) so that you won't have to use the `[0]` notation every time you need to access the `dict`s:

```
data["route-information"] = data["route-information"][0]
data["route-information"]["route-table"] = data["route-information"]["route-table"][0]

print(data["route-information"]["route-table"]["comment"])
```

Answer (score 0):

**MrGeek** is correct. Just to add more info

- `[]` are for JSON arrays, which are called list in Python
- `{}` are for JSON objects, which are called dict in Python

To get the value we do as follows:

```
data["route-information"][0]["route-table"][0]["comment"]
data["attributes"]["xmlns"]
```