# Iterating thru a not so ordinary Dictionary in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, loops, file, dictionary

Maybe it is ordinary issue regarding iterating thru a dict. Please find below imovel.txt file, whose content is as follows:

*{'Andar': ['primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro'], 'Apto': ['101','201','301']}*

As you can see this is not a ordinary dictionary, with a key value pair; but a key with a list as *key* and another list as *value*

My code is:

```
#/usr/bin/python

def load_dict_from_file():
    f = open('../txt/imovel.txt','r')
    data=f.read()
    f.close()
    return eval(data)
thisdict = load_dict_from_file()
for key,value in thisdict.items():
    print(value)
```

and yields :

> ['primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro'] ['101', '201', '301']

I would like to print a key,value pair like

> {'primeiro':'101, 'segundo':'201', 'terceiro':'301'}

Given such txt file above, is it possible?

Comment: use `json` module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the builtin `json` module to parse but either way, you'll still have the same structure.

There are a few things you can do.
If you know both of the base key names(`'Andar'` and `'Apto'`) you can do it as a one line `dict` comprehension by `zip`ping the values together.

```
# what you'll get from the file
thisdict = {'Andar': ['primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro'], 'Apto': ['101','201','301']}
# One line dict comprehension
newdict = {key: value for key, value in zip(thisdict['Andar'], thisdict['Apto'])}
print(newdict)
```

If you don't know the names of the keys, you could call `next` on an iterator assuming they're the first 2 lists in your structure.

```
# what you'll get from the file
thisdict = {'Andar': ['primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro'], 'Apto': ['101','201','301']}
# create an iterator of the values since the keys are meaningless here
iterator = iter(thisdict.values())
# the first group of values are the keys
keys = next(iterator, None)
# and the second are the values
values = next(iterator, None)
# zip them together and have dict do the work for you
newdict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(newdict)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot folks. Actually, I should have created a simple dictionary and write to file. That would be easier. Anyway I am very grateful to your help.

Answer (score 0):

As other folks have noted, that looks like JSON, and it'd probably be easier to parse it read through it as such. But if that's not an option for some reason, you can look through your dictionary this way if all of your lists at each key are the same length:

```
for i, res in enumerate(dict[list(dict)[0]]):
    ith_values = [elem[i] for elem in dict.values()]
    print(ith_values)
```

If they're all different lengths, then you'll need to put some logic to check for that and print a blank or do some error handling for looking past the end of the list.