# What is the best way to parse the following text in python

Tags: python, parsing

I want to use the following text, and parse it to python, but can't find a good way for that
the content is in a text file, and I want to use the data in python.
what kind of type to use? I want to populate it to a menu.

> ```
> "us-west-2": {
>   "focal-amd64": "ami-06e54d05255faf8f6",
>   "rhel7.5-x86_64": "ami-6f68cf0f",
>   "xenial-amd64": "ami-09b42c38b449cfa59",
>   "bionic-amd64": "ami-03804ed633fe58109",
>   "rhel8-x86_64": "ami-02f147dfb8be58a10"
> },
> "us-east-1": {
>   "oracle6.5": "ami-c034c5ad",
>   "rhel7.5-x86_64": "ami-0394fe9914b475c53",
>   "rhel7.7-x86_64": "ami-0916c408cb02e310b",
>   "trusty-amd64": "ami-0d859172c8670bbcd",
>   "xenial-amd64": "ami-028d6461780695a43",
>   "rhel7.6-x86_64": "ami-08a7d2bfef687328f",
>   "aws-ena": "ami-ccd280db",
>   "rhel8-x86_64": "ami-098f16afa9edf40be",
>   "rhel7.9-x86_64": "ami-005b7876121b7244d",
>   "bionic-amd64": "ami-07025b83b4379007e",
>   "centos6.9-x86_64": "ami-25491433",
>   "focal-amd64": "ami-0dba2cb6798deb6d8"
> },
> "us-east-2": {
>   "focal-amd64": "ami-07efac79022b86107",
>   "rhel7.9-x86_64": "ami-0d2bf41df19c4aac7",
> },
> "eu-central-1": {
>   "bionic-amd64": "ami-054e21e355db24124",
>   "xenial-amd64": "ami-05710338b6a5013d1",
> ```

> ```
> },
> "eu-west-1": {
>   "focal-amd64": "ami-06fd8a495a537da8b",
>   "rhel7.5-x86_64": "ami-02ace471",
>   "rhel7.6-x86_64": "ami-04c89a19fea29f1f0",
>   "rhel7.9-x86_64": "ami-020e14de09d1866b4",
>   "bionic-amd64": "ami-0727f3c2d4b0226d5",
>   "rhel8-x86_64": "ami-08f4717d06813bf00"
> },
> "ap-northeast-1": {
>   "bionic-amd64": "ami-003371bfa26192744",
>   "xenial-amd64": "ami-097beac0bacfefe65",
>   "focal-amd64": "ami-09b86f9709b3c33d4",
> }
> ```

Comment: google, "how to load a dictionary from file"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is almost in [json](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) format: if you
add enclosing brackets `{}` around it, and remove any commas `,` before a closing
bracket (there are 3 of them), your data will be fully json-compliant.

Now assuming your data is in a file called foobar.json, the following code will
parse it into a python dictionary named `d`:

```
import json

with open('foobar.json', 'r') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

You can now easily access and use your data, for example

```
print(d['us-west-2']['focal-amd64'])
```

will print `ami-06e54d05255faf8f6`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for