# How to Acess Json Integer using Python

Tags: python, json, variables

I'm learning JSON and I couldn't find anything about accessing Json Variables

JSON File:

```json
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "username": "LGLGLG"
    },
    {
      "username": "Number"
    },
    {
      "username": "Polly1"
    }
  ],
  "LGLGLG-U": "LGLGLG",
  "LGLGLG-P": "lol123",
  "LGLGLG-B": 0
}
```

I'm trying to access the JSON Integer LGLGLG-B

Comment: Reading them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file then accessing them like a dictionary via `json['key']`

Comment: like this  "a = json["LGLGLG-B"]"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse data in JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json is analogous to dictionaries in Python. So you can directly access element in Python by saying `dic[KEY]` to get the value where dic is the dictionary and KEY is the key against which you want to access the value. For your case, you can do something like below:

```
dic = {
  "Users" : [{
    "username" : "LGLGLG"
  }, {
    "username" : "Number"
  }, {
    "username" : "Polly1"
  }
  ],
  "LGLGLG-U" : "LGLGLG",
  "LGLGLG-P" : "lol123",
  "LGLGLG-B" : 0
}

result = dic["LGLGLG-B"]
print(result)
```

In your case the `dic` is dictionary and `LGLGLG-B` is the key and `0` is the value you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have JSON variables. It has dictionaries. The JSON in the file is just a string. You need to read lines from the file (which I will not show here), then use the python json library to load it into a dictionary then access it with bracket notation.

```
import json

your_json = """
{
  "Users" : [{
    "username" : "LGLGLG"
  }, {
    "username" : "Number"
  }, {
    "username" : "Polly1"
  }
  ],
  "LGLGLG-U" : "LGLGLG",
  "LGLGLG-P" : "lol123",
  "LGLGLG-B" : 0
}
"""

data = json.loads(your_json)
print(data["LGLGLG-B"])
```