# How to store API keys in environment variable? and call the same in google colab

Tags: python, environment-variables, gpt-3

I'm not sure how to make a ".json" file with my GPT-3 API key/environment variable, but I'd like to utilize it in Google Colab for automatic code generation.

Could someone please show me how to do this?

I want to get the API key from the.json file using the code below.

```
with open('GPT_SECRET_KEY.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
openai.api_key = data["API_KEY"]
```

Comment: Just make a file with `{"API_KEY": "1234"}` content, load it similarly to what you've shown. What's the problem?

Comment: Except that you can potentially compromise your private keys and make a big security whole in your system

Comment: Don't do this, you will end up exposing your private API key.  I don't use colab, so can't give a specific answer, look for a way to store "secrets" in your google account, then you should be able to use google's client library to retrieve that key, kinda like Github secrets

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Larionov, yes, I understood

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To read from a json file you do the following:

```
import json

my_key = ''
with open('GPT_SECRET_KEY.json', 'r') as file_to_read:
    json_data = json.load(file_to_read)
    my_key = json_data["API_KEY"]
```

The structure of your json file should look something like this.

```
{
    "API_KEY": "xxxxthis_is_the_key_you_are_targetingxxxx", 
    "API_KEY1": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "API_KEY2": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file) to a similar question if my answer was not clear enough.

Comment: Why are you repeating the code snippet from the question?  How is this a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Store your API keys in Google Colab Secrets

```
import os
from google.colab import userdata

os.environ["API_KEY"]=userdata.get("API_KEY")
```

[image]