# how do you extract data from json using python

Tags: python

I have this json file:

```
{
  "entityId": "12345",
  "displayName": "hostabc",
  "toRelationships": {
    "isProcessOf": [
      {
        "id": "proce123D00BB86",
        "type": "PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE"
      },
      {
        "id": "proc678DD0DBA4",
        "type": "PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE"
      },
      {
        "id": "proc978DD0DBA4",
        "type": "PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE"
      }
      
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to extract id fields under isProcessOf and build a data list.

I am new to python, how would I do this?

Comment: [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a list comprehension would do the job. You access dictionary values by its keys, so since you want to access `'id'`s of dictionaries in a list under the `'isProcessOf'` key, which in turn is under the `'toRelationships'` key, you can do it as:

```
out = [d['id'] for d in dct['toRelationships']['isProcessOf']]
```

Output:

```
['proce123D00BB86', 'proc678DD0DBA4', 'proc978DD0DBA4']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the json package in python and then read the data using list comprehension:

```
import json
file_dir = "<YOUR_FILE_DIR>"
with open(file_dir ) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
id_list = [process['id'] for process in data['toRelationships']['isProcessOf']]
```