# How can I access this copied JSON data?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I coped the following JSON data from a website, but I don't know how to access it with python.

[image: Screenshot of copied JSON data]

The result looks something like this:

```JSON
5b8e6b4b4f0ca1fbcd66e34e: {parentId: "52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45", nodeInfo: {position: 102,…}, id: "5b8e6b4b4f0ca1fbcd66e34e",…}
id: "5b8e6b4b4f0ca1fbcd66e34e"
name: "Parental Control"
nodeInfo: {position: 102,…}
description: "Companies that provide parental control solutions to keep children away from online risks"
position: 102
parentId: "52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45"
5b8e7c244f0c6c2263aaf8d2: {parentId: "5330677ae4b09e5482339b7a", nodeInfo: {position: 38,…}, id: "5b8e7c244f0c6c2263aaf8d2",…}
id: "5b8e7c244f0c6c2263aaf8d2"
name: "Anti Spyware"
nodeInfo: {position: 38,…}
description: "Companies that provides tools to remove spyware such as adware, keyboard loggers, hijackers etc"
position: 38
parentId: "5330677ae4b09e5482339b7a"
5b8f9d0f4f0c7c4d2daea8e8: {parentId: "52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a", nodeInfo: {position: 42,…}, id: "5b8f9d0f4f0c7c4d2daea8e8",…}
id: "5b8f9d0f4f0c7c4d2daea8e8"
name: "Anti Theft"
nodeInfo: {position: 42,…}
description: "Companies that provide anti-theft solutions with features such as remote lock, remote wipe, theft detection etc"
position: 42
parentId: "52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a"
```

How can I get access to the data in python using something like json.load()?

Desired Outputs:

```
parent = x["parentId"]
name = x["name"]
id = x["id"]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: By "copied", I assume you mean you copied and pasted it directly from a browser's developer's tools window? One way would be to make the request directly from your Python code. Another way would be to copy the page/document source instead of copying the text from the nicer looking user interface, to preserve the underlying formatting and structure.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can validate your json with an online editor such as: https://jsoneditoronline.org/. Then an answer like this should explain how to read it using python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file

Comment: Thanks David! I appreciate the resource!