# How do I print a part of a json file python

Tags: python, json

How do I print a part of a JSON file

```
[
    {   "ip": "192.168.0.135",   "timestamp": "1662977246", "ports": [ {"port": xxx, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 64} ] }
    ,
    {   "ip": "192.168.0.136",   "timestamp": "1662977246", "ports": [ {"port": xxx, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 64} ] }
]
```

In this case I want to  save all the IP addresses from the file into another JSON.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself to get that IP part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: An expected result would be nice to include dont want to make us guess

Answer (score 0):

A json object is pretty much a list of dictionaries in your case.

so you can iterate over your object an pick the info you want

```
your_json_object
new_json_object = []
for i in your_json_object:
    new_json_object.append[i["ip"]]
```

or with a list comprehension

```
new_json_object = [i["ip"] for i in your_json_object]
```

to save it:

```
with open("myfile.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(new_json_object, file)
```