# How to extract a single value from a nested Dictionary?

Tags: python

I have the following nested dictionary `my_dict` (which was originally JSON from a response to a request to an endpoint):

```
my_dict = {'SalesStatusResult': {'next_offset': -1,
  'customers': [{'caCustomerID': 'N872-1665582527-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': 'N872',
    'customertype': '',
    'blocked': False,
    'location': 'London',
    'expected_transaction_time': {'epoch': 1665582527,
     'tz': 'EDT',
     'dow': 'Wednesday',
     'time': '09:48',
     'date': '10/12/2022',
     'localtime': 1665568127},
    'estimated_order_time': {'epoch': 1665582527,
     'tz': 'EDT',
     'dow': 'Wednesday',
     'time': '09:48',
     'date': '10/12/2022',
     'localtime': 1665568127},
    'actual_order_time': {'epoch': 1665582527,
     'tz': 'EDT',
     'dow': 'Wednesday',
     'time': '09:48',
     'date': '10/12/2022',
     'localtime': 1665568127},
    'expected_settlement_time': {'epoch': 0,
     'tz': '',
     'dow': '',
     'time': '',
     'date': '',
     'localtime': 0},
    'status': 'Completed',
    'status_code': 1,
    'progress_percent': 100,
    'state_code': 2,
    'cust_id' : 'AD-17-C18'
  }]}}
```

Notably, when calling `type` on the object, it showed `dict`, not JSON.

I would like to extract the value in the `caCustomerID` key (which is "`N872-1665582527-adhoc-0:0`").

Separately, I would also like to get the `cust_id`, which is "`AD-17-C18`".

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What you have is....JSON.

Comment: I called `type()`, which resulted in `dict`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Comment: Use read_json and JSON normalize then get whatever sub elements you want.

Comment: This is just basic dict/list item accessing. What's the problem here?

Comment: @NelsonGon They already parsed JSON into dicts/lists.

Comment: The API is sending back JSON.  I use:  `response = requests.get(url auth=(user_name, api_key))`.  I'm not yet able to use `read_json` for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: starting from where you want and go upward: caCustomerID -> customers (this is a list) -> SalesStatusResult (this is a dictionary). After that, writing code which traverse back down:

```py
for record in my_dict["SalesStatusResult"]["customers"]:
    print(record["caCustomerID"])
    print(record["cust_id"])
```

Output:

```
N872-1665582527-adhoc-0:0
AD-17-C18
```