# how can i use the data i have in my json file to make the script work?

Tags: python, email, random

I'm recently learning python and I came across this exercise where I have to create a mail generator with the catchall, the latter must be inserted in an external json file, the only problem is that I can't tell the program to use the catchall which is placed in the json file, can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

this is part of code: need to fix email_format

```
for i in range (emails_number):
                letters_list = [string.digits, string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase]

                letters_list_to_str = "".join(letters_list)

                email_format = (json.data file)

                email_generated = "".join(random.choices(letters_list_to_str, k=chars)) + email_format

                print(email_generated)
email_gen()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading JSON from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find help here... provided you ask *good* questions! As a new user, you really should read [ask] to understand the way to ask questions that will get good answers. Specifically we need a minimal version of your current code (fine till here) and **enough input and expected output data** to reproduce your current problem. After reading twice your question I still cannot guess what is your precise problem, so I cannot help your...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a json file in general, use:

```
import json
with open(jsonfilepath, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

then you can access the information in the file like a dictionary:

```
email_format=data["catchall"]
```