# How to Parse JavaScript Type Html

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, web-scraping

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var modelData = [{"Id":958,"Date":"20160428","Title":"Design","Description":"London Auction 28 April 2016","Department":"Design","Location":"LONDON","Permalink":"/auctions/auction/UK050116","Year":"2016","Image":"/Xigen/image.ashx?path=\\\\diskstation\\website\\Certificates\\UK050116\\UK050116.jpg\u0026width=308\u0026height=222","addThis":" addthis:url=\"https://www.example.com/auctions/auction/UK050116\" ","results_html":"\u003cli class=\"expandable past-auction-exp closed\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\"\u003eVIEW RESULTS\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"panel\" style=\"display:none\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"/auctions/auction/UK050116\"\u003eOnline\u003c/a\u003e\u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"/Xigen/file.ashx?path=\\\\diskstation\\website\\Media\\Auction\\auctionResultsFile_UK050116.pdf\"\u003ePDF\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e","Download_catalog_html":"\u003cli class=\"expandable past-auction-exp closed\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\"\u003eCATALOGUES\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"panel\" style=\"display:none\"\u003e\u003ca target=\"_blank\" id=\"linkDownloadCatalog\" href=\"http://www.example.com/Xigen/file.ashx?path=\\\\diskstation\\website\\Certificates/UK050116/UK050116_catalog.pdf\"\u003eDownload Catalogue\u003c/a\u003e\u003ca href=\"/catalogues/buy\"\u003ePurchase Catalogue\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e"}]</script>
```

I want to parse Date, Title, Link, how can i parse it. I try to use PyQt4 but also couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, this is located inside the `script` tag, you can use the [`BeautifulSoup` module](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML and to locate the `script` by the same regular expression that you would use to extract the `modelData` value. Then, [after fixing the `modelData` value to be "loadable" with `json.loads()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18515887/771848), you would have a Python data structure you can easily work with:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

data = """
<script>
var modelData = [{"Id":958,"Date":"20160428","Title":"Design","Description":"London Auction 28 April 2016","Department":"Design","Location":"LONDON","Permalink":"/auctions/auction/UK050116","Year":"2016","Image":"/Xigen/image.ashx?path=\\\\diskstation\\website\\Certificates\\UK050116\\UK050116.jpg\u0026width=308\u0026height=222","addThis":" addthis:url=\"https://www.example.com/auctions/auction/UK050116\" ","results_html":"\u003cli class=\"expandable past-auction-exp closed\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\"\u003eVIEW RESULTS\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"panel\" style=\"display:none\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"/auctions/auction/UK050116\"\u003eOnline\u003c/a\u003e\u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"/Xigen/file.ashx?path=\\\\diskstation\\website\\Media\\Auction\\auctionResultsFile_UK050116.pdf\"\u003ePDF\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e","Download_catalog_html":"\u003cli class=\"expandable past-auction-exp closed\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\"\u003eCATALOGUES\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"panel\" style=\"display:none\"\u003e\u003ca target=\"_blank\" id=\"linkDownloadCatalog\" href=\"http://www.example.com/Xigen/file.ashx?path=\\\\diskstation\\website\\Certificates/UK050116/UK050116_catalog.pdf\"\u003eDownload Catalogue\u003c/a\u003e\u003ca href=\"/catalogues/buy\"\u003ePurchase Catalogue\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/li\u003e"}]
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile(r"var modelData = (\[.*?\])", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

s = pattern.search(script.text).group(1).encode('unicode_escape')
while True:
    try:
        result = json.loads(s)   # try to parse...
        break                    # parsing worked -> exit loop
    except Exception as e:
        # "Expecting , delimiter: line 34 column 54 (char 1158)"
        # position of unexpected character after '"'
        unexp = int(re.findall(r'\(char (\d+)\)', str(e))[0])
        # position of unescaped '"' before that
        unesc = s.rfind(r'"', 0, unexp)
        s = s[:unesc] + r'\"' + s[unesc+1:]
        # position of correspondig closing '"' (+2 for inserted '\')
        closg = s.find(r'"', unesc + 2)
        s = s[:closg] + r'\"' + s[closg+1:]

item = result[0]
print(item["Id"])
print(item["Title"])
```

Prints (works on Python 2 only in this state):

```
958
Design
```