# How do I read this stringified javascript variable into Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, yaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to read _pageData from https://www.simpliowebstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/aWfyh1 into Python 2.7.11 so that I can process it, using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Testing _pageData processing. """

import urllib2
import re
import ast
import json
import yaml

BASE_URL = 'https://www.simpliowebstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/aWfyh1'

def main():
    """ Do the business. """
    response = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL, None)
    results = re.findall('var _pageData = \\"(.*?)\\";</script>', response.read())
    first_result = results[0]
    # These all fail
    data = ast.literal_eval(first_result)
    # data = yaml.load(first_result)
    # data = json.loads(first_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "./temp.py", line 19, in main
    data = ast.literal_eval(first_result)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [[1,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,,\"at\",\"\",\"\",1450364255674,\"\",\"en_US\",false,[]\n,\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",,,true,\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/print?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/pdf?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",false,false,\"/maps/d\",\"maps/sharing\",\"//www.google.com/intl/en_US/help/terms_maps.html\",true,\"https://docs.google.com/picker\",[]\n,false,true,[[[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-regular-001.png\",143,25]\n,[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-regular-2x-001.png\",286,50]\n]\n,[[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-small-001.png\",113,20]\n,[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-small-2x-001.png\",226,40]\n]\n]\n,1,\"https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/_/js/k\\u003dmapspro.gmeviewer.en_US.8b9lQX3ifcs.O/m\\u003dgmeviewer_base/rt\\u003dj/d\\u003d0/rs\\u003dABjfnFWonctWGGtD63MaO3UZxCxF6UPKJQ\",true,true,false,true,\"US\",false,true,true,5,false]\n,[\"mf.map\",\"zBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"Hollywood, FL\",\"\",[-80.16005,26.01043,-80.16005,26.01043]\n,[-80.16005,26.01043,-80.16005,26.01043]\n,[[,\"zBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",\"Untitled layer\",\"\",[[[\"https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name\\u003dicons/onion/22-blue-dot.png\\u0026scale\\u003d1.0\"]\n,[]\n,1,1,[[,[26.01043,-80.16005]\n]\n,\"MDZBMzJCQjRBOTAwMDAwMQ~CjISKmdlby1tYXBzcHJvLm1hcHNob3AtbGF5ZXItNDUyOWUwMTc0YzhkNmI2ZBgAKAAwABIZACBawIJBU4Fe8v7vNSoAg0dtnhhVotEBLg\",\"vdb:\",\"zBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",[26.01043,-80.16005]\n,[0,-32]\n,\"06A32BB4A9000001\"]\n,[[\"Hollywood, FL\"]\n]\n,[]\n]\n]\n,,1.0,true,true,,,,[[\"zBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",1,,,,\"https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\\u0026lid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",,,,,0,2,true,[[[\"06A32BB4A9000001\",[[[26.01043,-80.16005]\n]\n]\n,[]\n,[]\n,0,[[\"name\",[\"Hollywood, FL\"]\n,1]\n,,[]\n,[]\n]\n,,0]\n]\n,[[[\"https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name\\u003dicons/onion/22-blue-dot.png\\u0026filter\\u003dff\\u0026scale\\u003d1.0\",[16,32]\n,1.0]\n,[[\"0000FF\",0.45098039215686275]\n,5000]\n,[[\"0000FF\",0.45098039215686275]\n,[\"000000\",0.25098039215686274]\n,3000]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n,[]\n,,,,,1]\n]\n,[2]\n,,,\"mapspro\",\"zBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",,true,false,false,\"\",2,false,\"https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",3807]\n]\n
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

var _pageData is in this format:

```
"[[1,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,,\"at\",\"\",\"\",1450364255674,\"\",\"en_US\",false,[]\n,\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",,,true,\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/print?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/pdf?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",false,false,\"/maps/d\",\"maps/sharing\",\"//www.google.com/intl/en_US/help/terms_maps.html\",true,\"https://docs.google.com/picker\",[]\n,false,true,[[[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-regular-001.png\",143,25]\n,[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-regular-2x-001.png\",286,50]\n]\n,[[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-small-001.png\",113,20]\n,[\"//www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/google-my-maps-logo-small-2x-001.png\",226,40]\n]\n]\n,1,\"https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/_/js/k\\u003dmapspro.gmeviewer.en_US.8b9lQX3ifcs.O/m\\u003dgmeviewer_base/rt\\u003dj/d\\u003d0/rs\\u003dABjfnFWonctWGGtD63MaO3UZxCxF6UPKJQ\",true,true,false,true,\"US\",false,true,true,5,false]\n,[\"mf.map\",\"zBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",\"Hollywood, FL\",\"\",[-80.16005,26.01043,-80.16005,26.01043]\n,[-80.16005,26.01043,-80.16005,26.01043]\n,[[,\"zBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",\"Untitled layer\",\"\",[[[\"https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name\\u003dicons/onion/22-blue-dot.png\\u0026scale\\u003d1.0\"]\n,[]\n,1,1,[[,[26.01043,-80.16005]\n]\n,\"MDZBMzJCQjRBOTAwMDAwMQ~CjISKmdlby1tYXBzcHJvLm1hcHNob3AtbGF5ZXItNDUyOWUwMTc0YzhkNmI2ZBgAKAAwABIZACBawIJBU4Fe8v7vNSoAg0dtnhhVotEBLg\",\"vdb:\",\"zBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",[26.01043,-80.16005]\n,[0,-32]\n,\"06A32BB4A9000001\"]\n,[[\"Hollywood, FL\"]\n]\n,[]\n]\n]\n,,1.0,true,true,,,,[[\"zBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",1,,,,\"https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\\u0026lid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.kq4rrF9BNRIg\",,,,,0,2,true,[[[\"06A32BB4A9000001\",[[[26.01043,-80.16005]\n]\n]\n,[]\n,[]\n,0,[[\"name\",[\"Hollywood, FL\"]\n,1]\n,,[]\n,[]\n]\n,,0]\n]\n,[[[\"https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name\\u003dicons/onion/22-blue-dot.png\\u0026filter\\u003dff\\u0026scale\\u003d1.0\",[16,32]\n,1.0]\n,[[\"0000FF\",0.45098039215686275]\n,5000]\n,[[\"0000FF\",0.45098039215686275]\n,[\"000000\",0.25098039215686274]\n,3000]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n,[]\n,,,,,1]\n]\n,[2]\n,,,\"mapspro\",\"zBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",,true,false,false,\"\",2,false,\"https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid\\u003dzBghbRiSwHlg.k2ATNtn6BCk0\",3807]\n]\n"
```

I've tried replacing the \" and \n and decoding the \uXXXX before using, without success. I've also tried replacing ,, with ,"", and ,'', without success.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not valid JSON. That's why `json.loads` can't decode it. It's not YAML either so that won't work. I'm not even going to speculate why you thought `ast.literal_eval` would work since it's obviously not good Python syntax.

Comment: This is a classic case of "Garbage in, garbage out". If the data coming into your program is corrupted or invalid, there's really not much you can do.

Comment: Two-Bit Alchemist, so is it not just a javascript var that has been stringified in some way?

Comment: Somewhat related, but not sure whether the approach is applicable (or advisable) here: [How do I automatically fix an invalid JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18514910/1639625)

Comment: Thanks tobias_k. http://jsonlint.com/ mentioned in that question says _pageData IS valid JSON. :-/ Ahh, but only with the quotes round it.

Comment: @karlic Did you paste it _with_ or _without_ the `"..."`? With, it's just a long string, as thus valid, but without, it reports an error at the first double `,`, as would be expected.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there are three kinds of syntactic errors in your string:

- `,` followed by `,`
- `[` followed by `,`
- `,` followed by `]`

Assuming that those are supposed to be `null` elements (or `''`?), you can just replace those in the original string -- exactly like you did for the `,,` case, but you missed the others. Also, you have to do the `,,` replacement twice, otherwise you will miss cases such as `,,,,`. Then, you can load the JSON string with `json.loads`.

```
>>> s = "your messed up json string"
>>> s = re.sub(r",\s*,",  ", null,", s)
>>> s = re.sub(r",\s*,",  ", null,", s)
>>> s = re.sub(r"\[\s*,", "[ null,", s)
>>> s = re.sub(r",\s*\]", ", null]", s)
>>> json.loads(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I started off using `ast.literal.eval(...)` because I was under the (mistaken?) impression that javascript arrays and Python lists were mutually compatible, so all I had to do was destringify _pageData.

However, I hadn't noticed that Python doesn't like `,,` `true`, `false` or `[,`. Fixing them does the trick (thank you @Two-Bit Alchemist and @tobias_k)

So, the following appears to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Testing _pageData processing. """

import urllib2
import re
import ast
import json
import yaml

BASE_URL = 'https://www.simpliowebstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/aWfyh1'

def main():
    """ Do the business. """
    response = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL, None)
    results = re.findall('var _pageData = \\"(.*?)\\";</script>', response.read())
    first_result = results[0]
    first_result = first_result.replace(',,,,,,', ',None,None,None,None,None,')
    first_result = first_result.replace(',,,,,', ',None,None,None,None,')
    first_result = first_result.replace(',,,,', ',None,None,None,')
    first_result = first_result.replace(',,,', ',None,None,')
    first_result = first_result.replace(',,', ',None,')
    first_result = first_result.replace('[,', '[None,')                    
    first_result = first_result.replace('\\"', '\'')
    first_result = first_result.replace('\\n', '')    
    first_result = first_result.replace('true', 'True')
    first_result = first_result.replace('false', 'False')  
    data = ast.literal_eval(first_result)
    for entry in  data:
        print entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Since this is supposed to be JSON, why not use `json.loads`?