# Replace double quotes inside double quotes in python

Tags: python, regex

JSON
    {
      "data": "{"id": "123", "unit": "metric", "location": "NYC"}"
    }

needs to be

{
  "data": "{'id': '123', 'unit': 'metric', 'location': 'NYC'}"
}

basically, any double quotes inside double quotes needs to become single quote

Tried

```
import re
re.sub('\w[: ]*"\w','',str)
```

Does not work

Comment: How the variable str  would be a valid string? don't shadow the inbuilt types

Comment: It should be a valid json

Comment: But the input [is not valid Python code in the first place](https://ideone.com/1QR4gg)!

Comment: JSON needs to be made valid. Have double quotes inside double quotes in JSON. need to make that single quote

Comment: I tested `(?<={.*?{.*?)"(?=.*?}.*?})` it worked fine

Comment: This should help you (I just tried and it worked): [How do I automatically fix an invalid JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18515887/1639625)