# Set all necessary keys in dictionary without nested loops (Python)

Tags: python, json

I have a script that requires certain keys from a JSON file. If any keys are missing or if the JSON file is corrupted (missing an end `}` or whatever) it will break. While trying to make a script that will open the JSON file and attempt to fix these error, I learned that `.setdefault()` does not set nested keys. I do not want to make nested for loops or make some crazy function that checks every key manually and so, after testing anything I could find on SO and still failing, I have come here. I have made a minimum reproducible example showing what should happen and what does happen. How can I get a function that will set all the required keys to be added for large dictionaries that are nested multiple times?

```py
# NOTE: to run this, make a test.json file
import json

#test.json: {"dict":{"Key3": "Value1"}
# What should be the output of this script: {"dict":{"Key3": "Value1", "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"}}

default_dict = {
    "dict":{
        "Key1": "Value1",
        "Key2": "Value2"
    }
}

# I want to make sure that all the keys in default_dict are present in test.json
# Any extra keys in test.json should be left alone

with open("test.json", "r+") as f:
    # First check if the file is a broken json file
    try:
        content: dict = json.load(f)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        # If it is, delete the file content and replace it with the default_dict
        # I would prefer a way to just fix the issue but I have no idea how that would be accomplished
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(json.dumps(default_dict, indent=4))
        content: dict = default_dict
    #Check that all keys are present
    for key in default_dict:
        content.setdefault(key, default_dict[key])
    # json dump
    #Delete the file content
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    json.dump(content, f, indent=4)


#Load the json file
with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    content: dict = json.load(f)
    print(content)

#Output (The exact same as before!):
"""
{'dict': {'Key3': 'Value1'}}
"""
```

Comment: You may get some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries/19829714#19829714

Comment: @Barmar, while I understand what that post is saying, the JSON is bound and even forced to have nested dicts because of one of the API's that are used from that data. It also needs to be a human readable file (normal JSON is, IMO) as it will likely be messed with by users.

Comment: I think you'll need nested loops.

Comment: What would be the most efficient way to do it then and how will it work if you don't know how deeply nested the JSON is?

Comment: If you don't know the nesting level, use a recursive function.

Comment: This might help with broken JSON's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18515887/17053202

Comment: A better approach may be to do a recursive merge of the JSON into the default.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/how-to-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries

Comment: Is the JSON really broken, or just missing some required keys?

Comment: Sometimes its really broken, sometimes its missing keys, and with the merge, if the same key occurs twice, which is used?

Comment: A key can't appear twice in a dictionary. `json.load()` will ignore one of the duplicates.

Comment: I mean in the two dicts being merged, if they both have the same key

Comment: The merge function should replace any existing keys with the value being merged.

Comment: Hmmmmm, I don't want the necessary keys to override new values so I'll need to add an if to check if a value exists and keep the value if it does. It should only add the ones that don't exist.

Comment: Why don't you want them to override? I thought these were just defaults in case the key is missing. If it's not missing in the JSON, you should use the JSON value.

Comment: In case it's missing. If they've been modified by the user and they have changed a value I need to keep the value set by the user.

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything about the user. There's just `default_dict` and `test.json`. The JSON file takes precedence.

Comment: If there's a third source, you can do two merges. First override the defaults with the JSON file, then override that with the user-supplied values.

Comment: Ok I think we're almost on the same page. The `test.json` can be modified by users of the application and therefore those keys take precedence but if the keys are missing they will be taken from `default_dict`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. You start with `default_dict`, then replace its elements with the corresponding elements from `test.json`. So the JSON takes precedence.

Comment: And, this is less of actual coding and more preference, if the `test.json` is broken, how would you handle it to try and salvage as much data from the `test.json` as possible?

Comment: There's no excuse for broken JSON, and no reliable way to recover from it. You linked to another question, I guess you could try something from that, but I recommend fixing the source.

Comment: If you add all of this into an answer I will mark it. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the merge the other way. Start with `default_dict` as the value, then merge the JSON into it.

```
result = default_dict

with open("test.json") as f:
    try:
        new_content = json.load(f)
        merge_recursive(result, new_content)
```

You can find ways to implement `merge_recursive()` at [How to merge dictionaries of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/how-to-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries). Some of the answers there will not override an existing key; either modify them to allow this, or find another answer.